# Disable the web browser in SSMS/ Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, web, browser, ssms, disable

The browsers in these tools are being used to access inappropriate content, and need to be disabled entirely.

I have uninstalled internet explorer from the computers, but the web browser window still functions as normal. I've also looked through the options window in SSMS and VS and had no luck.

I'm guessing there are some files in the directories which pertain to the web browser and which I could delete to disable it. Does anyone know what these files are or have any other means of doing this? Thanks

Comment: If people are using applications inappropriately, seems that their priviledges should be revoked. Also, controlling what websites people can access should be done at the firewall level. Stop people accessing the internet, and they have no need for the browser. The problem isn't that SSMS has a browser, it's that you're letting the users have access to sites they shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I've already looked into firewall level restrictions but they're not an option for our present set up. The current PC level restrictions are perfect for our needs except that they don't apply to VS and SSMS, and the web browser is of no use to us anyway so it makes sense to remove it.